# CppCodeGenerator parse managed C++

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, codedom

I am looking to parse managed C++ files into a CodeDOM tree (or any other c# representation, for that matter). I see that CppCodeGenerator has been removed in .NET4, and it does not provide a Parse(string) implementation. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with CodeDom; according to other posters there's no help for it anyway.

If you want robust, accurate parsers for C#, VB.net,  VC++ and managed VC++ (and many other languages) you might consider our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [family of language front-ends](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds).

Using a front-end, DMS parses source into a detailed AST enabling further analysis, transformation, and generation of valid source code from modified ASTs.  No, you can't manipulate these trees using C# calls; you have to do that from inside DMS, which offers a complete ecosystem for these tasks.  But you can manipulate them from inside DMS in virtually arbitary ways.